# InAppBrowser.open with "_system" param is opening links inside webview (only in iOS)

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I've been fighting against this weird problem in a Cordova app (iOS and Android) since yesterday, so I think is time to ask for a little help.

I have the following code running on "deviceready" event:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    delete window.open;

    $(document).on('mousedown','a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.hostname !== window.location.hostname) {
            const url = $(this).attr('href');
            cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_system', 'location=yes');
        }
    });
}, false);
```

This is working perfectly for Android. In iOS it opens the link in the system browser and when I come back to my app it is also opened there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution. The problem apparently was using the "mousedown" event, switching over to "click" did the job. I also had to move the `e.preventDefault` call to the `if` block, otherwise internal links won't work.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    delete window.open;

    $(document).on('click','a', function(e) {
        if (this.hostname !== window.location.hostname) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const url = $(this).attr('href');
            cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_system', 'location=yes');
        }
    });
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for ios and android

```
window.open(urlValue, "_system", "location=yes");
```